# Flag first instance of an event occurring contingent on other variable's value

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

New to R and to solving such a problem as the one below, so not sure about how certain functionality is achieved in particular instances.

I have a dataframe as such:

```
df <- data.frame(DATETIME = seq(from = as.POSIXct('2014-01-01 00:00', tz = "GMT"), to = as.POSIXct('2014-01-01 06:00', tz = "GMT"), by='15 mins'),
                 Price = c(23,22,23,24,27,31,33,34,31,26,24,23,19,18,19,19,23,25,26,26,27,30,26,25,24),
                 TroughPriceFlag = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
df <- data.table(df)

df
               DATETIME Price TroughPriceFlag
 1: 2014-01-01 00:00:00    23           0
 2: 2014-01-01 00:15:00    22           1
 3: 2014-01-01 00:30:00    23           0
 4: 2014-01-01 00:45:00    24           0
 5: 2014-01-01 01:00:00    27           0
 6: 2014-01-01 01:15:00    31           0
 7: 2014-01-01 01:30:00    33           0
 8: 2014-01-01 01:45:00    34           0
 9: 2014-01-01 02:00:00    31           0
10: 2014-01-01 02:15:00    26           0
11: 2014-01-01 02:30:00    24           0
12: 2014-01-01 02:45:00    23           0
13: 2014-01-01 03:00:00    19           0
14: 2014-01-01 03:15:00    18           1
15: 2014-01-01 03:30:00    19           0
16: 2014-01-01 03:45:00    19           0
17: 2014-01-01 04:00:00    23           0
18: 2014-01-01 04:15:00    25           0
19: 2014-01-01 04:30:00    26           0
20: 2014-01-01 04:45:00    26           0
21: 2014-01-01 05:00:00    27           0
22: 2014-01-01 05:15:00    30           0
23: 2014-01-01 05:30:00    26           0
24: 2014-01-01 05:45:00    25           0
25: 2014-01-01 06:00:00    24           0
```

What I wish to do is two things:

(1) From where we observe a TroughPrice, flag the first instance where the price has risen by 10 or more dollars. That is, find the first instance where deltaPrice >= 10 since the trough price.

As an example: from the trough price of 22 (row 2), in the next interval price is increased to 23 which is a change of 1 dollar, so no flag. From the trough price of 22 (again row 2, since always with reference to the trough price in question), two intervals later the price is 24 dollars, so the price has increased by 2 dollars since the trough, so again no flag. However, from the trough price of 22, 5 intervals later the price has increased to 33 dollars, which is an increase of 11 dollars and is the first time the price has increased above 10 dollars. Thus the flag is 1.

(2) Determine the number of 15 minute periods which have passed between the trough price and the first instance the price has risen by 10 or more dollars.

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
              DATETIME Price TroughPriceFlag FirstOver10CentsFlag CountPeriods
1  2014-01-01 00:00:00    23           0                    0           NA
2  2014-01-01 00:15:00    22           1                    0            5
3  2014-01-01 00:30:00    23           0                    0           NA
4  2014-01-01 00:45:00    24           0                    0           NA
5  2014-01-01 01:00:00    27           0                    0           NA
6  2014-01-01 01:15:00    31           0                    0           NA
7  2014-01-01 01:30:00    33           0                    1           NA
8  2014-01-01 01:45:00    34           0                    0           NA
9  2014-01-01 02:00:00    31           0                    0           NA
10 2014-01-01 02:15:00    26           0                    0           NA
11 2014-01-01 02:30:00    24           0                    0           NA
12 2014-01-01 02:45:00    23           0                    0           NA
13 2014-01-01 03:00:00    19           0                    0           NA
14 2014-01-01 03:15:00    18           1                    0            8
15 2014-01-01 03:30:00    19           0                    0           NA
16 2014-01-01 03:45:00    19           0                    0           NA
17 2014-01-01 04:00:00    23           0                    0           NA
18 2014-01-01 04:15:00    25           0                    0           NA
19 2014-01-01 04:30:00    26           0                    0           NA
20 2014-01-01 04:45:00    26           0                    0           NA
21 2014-01-01 05:00:00    27           0                    0           NA
22 2014-01-01 05:15:00    30           0                    1           NA
23 2014-01-01 05:30:00    26           0                    0           NA
24 2014-01-01 05:45:00    25           0                    0           NA
25 2014-01-01 06:00:00    24           0                    0           NA
```

I'm not really sure where to start, since the time gaps can be quite large and I've only used indexing in the context of a few steps forward/backward. Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have no price below 10. And there is no `TroughPrice`.

Comment: It's not a price below 10.. It is the first instance where the price has risen by 10 or more dollars.

Eg. from the trough price of 22, the next interval the price is increased to 23, this is a change of 1 dollar, so no flag.

From the trough price of 22, two intervals later the price is 24 dollars, so the price has increased by 2 dollars since the trough, so no flag.

From the trough price of 22, 5 intervals later the price has increased to 33 dollars, which is an increase of 11 dollars and is the first time the price has increased above 10 dollars. Thus the flag is 1.

Comment: So this is not clear from your question. You mean a positive delta of 10 dollars between 2 consecutive time stamps. Please move your comment into your question.

Comment: Delta of 10 dollars since the troughpriceflag. I will edit accordingly, thanks!

Comment: Hopefully that is more clear, thanks @pascal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain operation with `data.table` package, the idea would be to group by `cumsum` of the `ThroughPriceFlag`:

```
library(data.table)

df[, col1:=pmatch(Price-Price[1]>10,T, nomatch=0), cumsum(TroughPriceFlag)][
   , count:=which(col1==1)-1,cumsum(TroughPriceFlag)][
   TroughPriceFlag==0, count:=NA]

#> df
#               DATETIME Price TroughPriceFlag col1 count
# 1: 2014-01-01 00:00:00    23               0    0    NA
# 2: 2014-01-01 00:15:00    22               1    0     5
# 3: 2014-01-01 00:30:00    23               0    0    NA
# 4: 2014-01-01 00:45:00    24               0    0    NA
# 5: 2014-01-01 01:00:00    27               0    0    NA
# 6: 2014-01-01 01:15:00    31               0    0    NA
# 7: 2014-01-01 01:30:00    33               0    1    NA
# 8: 2014-01-01 01:45:00    34               0    0    NA
# 9: 2014-01-01 02:00:00    31               0    0    NA
#10: 2014-01-01 02:15:00    26               0    0    NA
#11: 2014-01-01 02:30:00    24               0    0    NA
#12: 2014-01-01 02:45:00    23               0    0    NA
#13: 2014-01-01 03:00:00    19               0    0    NA
#14: 2014-01-01 03:15:00    18               1    0     8
#15: 2014-01-01 03:30:00    19               0    0    NA
#16: 2014-01-01 03:45:00    19               0    0    NA
#17: 2014-01-01 04:00:00    23               0    0    NA
#18: 2014-01-01 04:15:00    25               0    0    NA
#19: 2014-01-01 04:30:00    26               0    0    NA
#20: 2014-01-01 04:45:00    26               0    0    NA
#21: 2014-01-01 05:00:00    27               0    0    NA
#22: 2014-01-01 05:15:00    30               0    1    NA
#23: 2014-01-01 05:30:00    26               0    0    NA
#24: 2014-01-01 05:45:00    25               0    0    NA
#25: 2014-01-01 06:00:00    24               0    0    NA
```

Comment: Either your output or OP expected result is incorrect.

Comment: corrected, there was indeed a typo in my code, i set NA depending on col1 whereas it's based on value 0 for troughPriceFlag!